# React-Redux state management: Proper way to store "selected" list items?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an email app. The inbox page shows the list of emails; each list item has a checkbox, allowing the user to select multiple emails (which they can later delete, move, etc.).

My question is, what is the proper way to store the 'selected emails' state? Right now, my state has a list of email objects with a few properties (id, subject, sender, etc.). Should I add another property "isSelected"? Or should I create an entirely new state in the Store, say "selectedEmails", and then just have that save an array of id's of currently selected emails?

Part of me doesn't want to add the "isSelected" property to the email list, because I don't feel this is information that an email object should be concerned about. But storing another array of id's of selected emails would make it more difficult to update the UI based on which emails are selected or not (for example, it would be easy to update the UI if I could simply check the email.isSelected property, compared to checking the "selectedEmails" array for each email item to see if it is selected or not). Or is there an alternate, better solution? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add it to the email list object. You can create another data structure, or just work with the check boxes directly because they already hold their own state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the selectedIds in a separate array you could have the emails list normalized and then have a list of the selectedIds, and use selectors to get the selectedIds.

Imagine a normalized state such as:

```
{
  ids: [1, 2],
  map: {
   1: {id: 1, subject: '1', ...},
   2: {id: 2, subject: '2', ...}
  },
  selectedIds: [2]
}
```

And then you would have a selector function to get the state such as:

```
const getEmails = (state) => {
  return state.emails.ids.map(id => {
    ...state.emails.map[id], 
    isSelected: state.emails.selectedIds.indexOf(id) !== -1
  });
};
```

But I believe this selector's complexity is too high, I would just update the email object itself with a isSelected prop.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a better way to go about it, as opposed to creating a new state in the store, as well as a new reducer. Although, after thinking about it, I don't think it is even necessary to have a separate array for id's. I could simply have the original array of all emails, and then an array of selected emails, which would hold a reference to each email object that has been selected, so I wouldn't need to worry about wasting memory (assuming I understand the redux state object correctly)

Comment: I like encapsulating the "isSelected" state as a separate state property simply b/c it represents a UI state and is not part of the object, but I battle with this. Any recommended resources to learn more about this?